# Why is this php reloading when I used AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a php page (**index.php**) with two jQuery slider that displays the value in 2 input text box that submits those values to another php page (**seatmap.php**) included in the **index.php**. But how come when I click the Submit Button with an onclick event using AJAX, the page reloads/refreshes when in fact I used AJAX for that. I feel like the ajax function isn't being used at all. Can someone please help me? Any ideas on how to make it work? Any kind of help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Here is the **index.php** code:

```
<form method="POST" action="index.php">

<p class="submitSlider">
    <input type="SUBMIT" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="showAvailable()">
</p>

<div id="slider1Containter">

    <p>
        Time Range: <span class="slider-time">10:00 AM</span>
    </p>

    <input type="number" id="startShift" name="startShiftSlider">

    <div id="slider"></div>

</div>

<div id="slider2Containter">

    <p>
        Time Range: <span class="slider-time2">10:00 AM</span>
    </p>

    <input type="number" id="endShift" name="endShiftSlider">

    <div id="slider2"></div>

</div>

</form>
```

And the code for the **seatmap.php**:

```
<?php  
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
session_start();

$startShift = $_POST['startShiftSlider'];
$endShift = $_POST['endShiftSlider'];

$_SESSION['startShiftValue'] = $startShift;
$_SESSION['endShiftValue'] = $endShift;

$finalStartShiftValue = $_SESSION['startShiftValue'];
$finalEndShiftValue = $_SESSION['endShiftValue'];

echo $finalStartShiftValue;
echo $finalEndShiftValue;
}
?>
```

And for the **functions.js** page:

```
function showAvailable(){
  var xmlhttp;

  var getStartShift;
  var getEndShift;

  if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else{
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
      if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      {
        getStartShift = document.getElementById("startShift").value;
        getEndShift = document.getElementById("endShift").value;

        xmlhttp.open("GET","seatmap.php?sendStartShift="+getStartShift+"&sendEndShift="+getEndShift,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
      }
  }  
}
```

This might be a possible duplicate of another question.

Answer (score 1):

The submit buttons default behaviour is still executed when it is clicked (submitting the page aka 'refreshing'). You need to disable the default behaviour.

```
<input type="SUBMIT" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="showAvailable(); return false;">
```

Edit: to answer your comment:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
  if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
    alert(myRequest.responseText);
  }
}  

getStartShift = document.getElementById("startShift").value;
getEndShift = document.getElementById("endShift").value;
xmlhttp.open("GET","seatmap.phpsendStartShift="+getStartShift+"&sendEndShift="+getEndShift,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: I replaced it with this. But now when I click the button the values doesn't show up. Thank you for helping though. Any ideas how?

Comment: a quick guess is because you send() your request inside of the readystatechange function. This is not executed until you call `.send()`. Move the last two lines xmlhttp.open & xmlhttp.send() beload the onreadystatechange definition.

Comment: I've updated my answer again. It should submit and then alert() the data that php generates. It's then up to you to parse that data and insert it back into the dom.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add return false in your showAvailable function and update the onclick to onsubmit.

HTML:

```
<input type="SUBMIT" name="submit" value="Submit" onsubmit="return showAvailable();">
```

JS Code:

```
function showAvailable(){
  var xmlhttp;

  var getStartShift;
  var getEndShift;

  if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else{
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
      if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      {
        getStartShift = document.getElementById("startShift").value;
        getEndShift = document.getElementById("endShift").value;

        xmlhttp.open("GET","seatmap.php?sendStartShift="+getStartShift+"&sendEndShift="+getEndShift,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
      }
  }  
return false;
}
```

Comment: This won't work. showAvailable() returning false is not passed back into the DOM. You'd have to couple this example with `onclick="return showAvailable()"` however i don't recommend this as showAvailable() returning false for valid execution doesn't make any sense.

Comment: It still reloads man. And the slider handles goes back to their default values.